# Create SQL server connection between the client computers and Server computer from a form

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a form like this:

[image]

How can I use these fields to open a connection to the database?

Comment: Generally, you don't want to use just one connection for an entire app. The connection pooling feature in ADO.Net means it really is better to create a brand new connection object for most queries. So while it's perfectly fine to ask for connection information like this, typically the button would just say something more like "Test" or "Save".

Comment: that means have to create a DBConnection class?

Answer (score 0):

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection()) 
{
   conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=[SERVERNAME];Initial Catalogue=[DATABASENAME];User id=[USERNAME];Password=[PASSWORD];";
   conn.Open();

   // use the connection here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use connection builder

```
 SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder =  new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

        // Supply the additional values.
        builder.DataSource = Server.Text +":" Port.Text;
        builder.UserID = userName;
        builder.Password = userPassword;
        builder.InitialCatelog = Database.Text;
 using (SqlConnection connection = 
                new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                // Now use the open connection.
                Console.WriteLine("Database = " + connection.Database);
            }
```